# how nestjs setting certbot?

Tags: nestjs, certbot

I'm going to use certbot based on nestjs. So I want to set up nestjs to read the txt file under /.well-known/acme-challenge/. However, I don't know how to set it up to read the txt file under that path. If you use the ServerStaticModule, it keeps loading index.html. Could you tell me how to set it up?

--my nestjs app.module.ts--

[image]

--Result--
[image]

result is importing /.well-known/acme-challeng/index.html. I want to bring file.txt. What should I do?

Comment: I solved it by putting the code below in the main.ts.

Comment: ` const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
  cors: true
  // httpsOptions
 });
 app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));`